# Touch: WPF Touching Outside Modal Dialog Causes Unhandled 10th Touch Later

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, touch

I found in a WPF application on Windows 10 with a touch screen, if the user touches the **outside** of a modal dialog, **on the main application window**, , so that it will blink and chime, count that as your tap #1, tap on the modal dialog, then continue tap around on the other buttons, when you count your tap #11, it won't response.
If the user touches the **outside** multiple times, then later there will be multiple non-responsive touches, exactly 10 touches later. This is easily reproducible, looks like a WPF/Windows 10 bug to me.

Please see the detailed description and a very simple program to demonstrate this program: [WpfTouchTest at github](https://github.com/GuangSunshine/WpfTouchTest/blob/main/README.md)

I posted my question on [Microsoft Q & A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/346813/windows-10-touch-event-backing-up.html), no response yet.

Any one noticed similar problem on touch? Any suggestions on how to fix/work-around it? Thanks!

Comment: I could not reproduce it with Surface Pro 4 on Windows 10 (20H2). It might be hardware dependent.

Comment: @emoacht Thanks for your information! I don't have a surface, but tried on a third part touch screen monitor, and a Lenovo Yoga Flex 5. Did you try my sample program? It seems only happens for WPF programs, not UWP program.

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Comment: @emoacht Hmm.. I just got a Surface Pro 4 with Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363, I can still reproduce the problem using my program. Would you mind trying it again? Please notice you need to tap the main application window area while the modal message is showing, so that it will blink and chime, count that as your tap #1, then continue tap around on the other buttons, when you count your tap #11, it won't response.

Comment: I tried again and could not reproduce it. The visual effects surrounding a dialog are always the same regardless of the number of touches.

Comment: @emoacht, thanks for trying again! By "visual effects" do you mean the blinking of the modal dialog when you touch outside on the main application? Yes that blinking visual effect and chime sound effect are always there.     Maybe I didn't make it clear, I meant if you touch on the main application once (#1) to let the modal message box (dialog) blink, then touch "OK" on the dialog to close it (#2), then touch any of those "click me" buttons for another 8 times (#3 ~#10), you will then find the #11 touch will not get any response. That's what I meant. Would you please have another try? Thanks!

Comment: I see. You didn't described to close the dialog. I found that only 9th tough does not get the response.

Comment: Thanks @emoacht! So you could reproduce it. Whether it's 9th or 10th depends on when do you start counting. Any thoughts on how to solve this? Thank you!